# Return cell after using sort_value Pandas Python 2.7

Tags: python, pandas, sorting

How do I get the value from a cell and/or the index when using "sort_values"?

Code example:

```
print new_eu.sort_values("Parts", ascending=False).head(2)
```

out:

```
     series    ts_log       Parts one_or_null
28  1.1772  1.177335  245.332718           1
24  1.1776  1.177543  110.030174           1
```

How can I get "24" (second index value) for example or "1.177335" as an array or float?

I know I can get values with the code:
print new_eu.iloc[28,0]

But I want a code to sort the column "Parts" with "sort_values" and extract the cell info like X=24 then use it with:
print new_eu.iloc[X,0]

Comment: Its not clear what you're asking. What is the desired output? The and/or makes me think your issue goes back to not using `inplace=True` in your actual code.

Comment: `new_eu.sort_values("Parts", ascending=False).head(2).loc[24,'ts_log']`??

Comment: Desired output is "24" (second index value) and/or "1.177335" (under ts_log).

Comment: What do you mean by `and/or`?

Comment: new_eu.sort_values("Parts", ascending=False).head(2).iloc[2,'ts_log']
Gives 
"IndexError: single positional indexer is out-of-bounds "
And 
new_eu.sort_values("Parts", ascending=False).head(2).iloc[0,'ts_log']
Gives 
ValueError: Location based indexing can only have [integer, integer slice (START point is INCLUDED, END point is EXCLUDED), listlike of integers, boolean array] types

Comment: By "and/or" I would like to get both those values like:
[24]
or   
[1.177335]

Comment: You mean to say getting the minimum values from index and that specific column then use `[new_eu.sort_values("Parts", ascending=False).head(2).index.min()]`, `[new_eu.sort_values("Parts", ascending=False).head(2)['column_name'].min()]`

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`iloc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html) for select by position:

```
df = new_eu.sort_values("Parts", ascending=False).head(2)

#for select second value of index
idx = df.index[1]

#for select first row and second column
val = df.iloc[0, 1]

#for select first row
row = df.iloc[0]

#for select second column
col = df.iloc[:, 1]

#for select first row and column ts_log
val = df.iloc[0, df.columns.get_loc('ts_log')]
```

Or use [`loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html):

```
#for select first row and column ts_log
val = df.loc[df.index[0], 'ts_log']
```

If want minimal value of column or of index:

```
idx = df.index.min()
val = df['ts_log'].min()
```

Comment: I think OP is looking for getting the minimum value from index and column I dont know

Comment: Thanks, but the point is to use the result from "sort_values".
If I for example use 
print new_eu.loc[new_eu.index[0], 'ts_log']
Output is:
1.17750997222
And not in "sort_values" output.

Comment: yes, my first row is `df = new_eu.sort_values("Parts", ascending=False).head(2)`

Comment: I assign output of sorting code to variable `df` and then using it. Is it better as still sorting like `new_eu.sort_values("Parts", ascending=False).head(2).index[1]` and then `new_eu.sort_values("Parts", ascending=False).head(2).iloc[0, 1]`, because it is counted only once

Comment: Thanks jezrael, just want I wanted!

Answer (score 0):

You should still be able to get the index location by:

`new_eu.iloc[24]`

or `new_eu.iloc[24, 1]` if you want just that "cell"

Comment: The point is to get [24] from "sort_values" like "x" and then use 
new_eu.iloc[X]